# How are the bar and colon used in this function?

Tags: notation, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

A search on fuzzy logic led me to a [Zadeh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotfi_A._Zadeh#Fuzzy_sets_and_systems) function in the context of "[synthesis of fuzzy logic functions given in tabular form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic#Synthesis_of_fuzzy_logic_functions_given_in_tabular_form)".  The following expression is defined as a row of a choice table of a two arguments function:

> x₁ ≤ x₂ ≤ x̄₂ ≤ x̄₁ : x₂

[Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Bar.html) tells me that the [macron](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Macron.html) may connote the mean of a set, a [complex conjugate](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexConjugate.html), the [complement of a set](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Complement.html), the [order type of a set](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrderType.html), or absolute value.  Similarly, a colon has multiple meanings.

**Q: What is the meaning of the macron and colon in this expression?**

Comment: Notional questions tend to be very difficult to answer in abstract, except for a handful of universal notations. Reproducing the surrounding context and providing a reference would greatly increase the chance of your question being answered.

Comment: @StellaBiderman Thanks for the advice.  I've amended the question to link to where I found the expression, and the context.